# Add eventListener inside a loop and create a listener function that depends on the loop but still works after loop finishes

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, addeventlistener

Code as follows:

```
var classToAdd = 'myClass';

var addClass = function(el, cn) {
  if (el.classList.contains(cn)) {
    return;
  } else {
    el.classList.add(cn);
  }
};

var bundles = [
  {
    selectedActivators: [`array containing 2 DOM objects`],
    target: `DOM object`
  },
  {
    selectedActivators: [`array containing 2 DOM objects`],
    target: `DOM object`
  },
  {
    selectedActivators: [`array containing 2 DOM objects`],
    target: `DOM object`
  }
];

for (var k=0; k<bundles.length; k++) {
  for (var l=0; l<bundles[k].selectedActivators.length; l++) {
    console.log(bundles[k].selectedActivators[l]); // log #1
    console.log(bundles[k].target); // log #2
    bundles[k].selectedActivators[l].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      console.log(bundles[k]); // log #3
      addClass(bundles[k].target, classToAdd);
    });
    bundles[k].selectedActivators[l].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      removeClass(bundles[k].target, classToAdd);
    });
  } 
}
```

Logs #1 and #2 work exactly as expected so the objects are fine before they go into the event listener, but log #3 prints: `undefined`.

I understand that bundles[k] is not defined anymore when I go to the page and hover over the eventListener target because the loop has already finished, but how do I solve this? That target depends on the same loop

Comment: Are you able to use `let k = 0` instead of `var k = 0`?

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is messing up the [**Closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) because it passes the same variable (`k`) to all the `addClass` calls. So when a `addClass` is invoked, it's look for the up-to-date value of `k` (which will be equal to the length of the array `.length` thus undefined index). That happens because the [**Scope**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) of `for` remains the same until it is exited. So instead use `forEach` which surrounds each element by a different scope (scope of the callback) thus solving your problem. Like this:

```
bundles.forEach(function(bundlesK) {
  bundlesK.selectedActivators.forEach(function(selActiv) {
    selActiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      addClass(bundlesK.target, classToAdd);
    });
    selActiv.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      removeClass(bundlesK.target, classToAdd);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: @Ben try put `console.log` inside `addclass` and `removeclass`!